# Multilevel list in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, multi-level

I want to have automatically created the numbering of a list of items in html, something like this:

```
1. Heading 1
   Text
1.1 Heading 1.1
   Text
2. Heading 2
  Text
2.1 Heading 2.1
   Text
2.2 Heading 2.2
   Text
```

It is the same as using Word, Latex or any other that allows you setting styles.

Any JavaScript, CSS, etc?

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support? IE7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done through css/HTML

The following site has a nice tutorial on how to: http://doctype.com/make-ordered-list-go-up-111213-instead-123

Comment: +1, but note that this isn't supportet by IE7 and below: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t21

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I think it gets down to some javascript. ordered lists etc. will not help you out here. Maybe you can write some smart script using jquery based on child/parent logic that does the trick for you.